# Flutter package: How get parent BuildConfig.java class values?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, build

I'm implementing a flutter package, I'm trying to retrieve values ​​from the Android BuildConfig file of the parent application, is this possible?

I tried code like this:

```
val packageName = flutterActivity?.packageName
if (packageName != null) {
    val value = Class.forName(packageName + ".BuildConfig").getField("FLAVOR").get(null) as String
    print(value)
}
```

But file is not found...

Comment: Maybe the package name of the application is different than the package of the `flutterActivity`? You should be able to simple include `BuildConfig` though, without having to use reflection.

Comment: How include this file ?

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, it should just come up automatically when you type `BuildConfig`. Otherwise, you can import it from your application's package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem by using :

```
    private var flutterActivity: Activity? = null


    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        this.flutterActivity = binding.activity
    }

    /// Get The Build Flavor config.
    private fun getFlavor(result: Result) {
        flutterActivity?.let {
            val pack = it.localClassName.split(".").dropLast(1).joinToString(".")
            val flavor =
                Class.forName(pack.plus(".BuildConfig")).getField("FLAVOR").get(null) as String
            result.success(flavor)
        } ?: run {
            result.success(null)
        }
    }
```